# LoadError with Rakefile when trying to rake db:migrate in a Rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar, rails-engines

I forked the fullcalendar_engine rails engine from: https://github.com/vinsol/fullcalendar-rails-engine.git

When I tried to add an attribute (:task) to the Event resource and rake db:migrate, I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- /Users/myuser/fullcalendar-rails-engine/test/dummy/Rakefile
/Users/myuser/fullcalendar-rails-engine/Rakefile:19:in `load'
/Users/myuser/fullcalendar-rails-engine/Rakefile:19:in `'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `'
Tasks: TOP => load_app
```

Anyone have any idea how to get this to work? I'm new to rails engines.

Answer (score 0):

The Rakefile refers to a file that doesn't seem to be in the repo - `APP_RAKEFILE = File.expand_path("../test/dummy/Rakefile", __FILE__)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at that project's `Rakefile`, you'll notice there is a line in there that has:

```
APP_RAKEFILE = File.expand_path("../test/dummy/Rakefile", __FILE__)
```

Look at the project's directory structure and you'll notice that that the `test/dummy` directory does not exist, thus the `LoadError`.  Read over the [installation instructions](https://github.com/vinsol/fullcalendar-rails-engine#installation) and make to include the Gem in your Rails 4 app's Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing.

I hooked the engine into a dummy parent application and ran *bundle update* to use the latest update from the forked gem. Initially when I tried migrating the changes from the engine this way, it didn't work. My problem was that I was *bundle install*ing and not bundle updating. Bundle install will look for any version changes but since I didn't change my version, it didn't see my migrations. I ran *rake fullcalendar_engine:install:migrations* to copy over my engine migrations into the parent app and then ran *rake db:migrate*.